# Accessing promise result using async await and axios get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am calling a function in my reducer which returns a promise and I want to assign the promise result of it to an existing initialState field from my reducer. I'm not sure how to do this though. I've tried some solutions I saw online but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: I am able to print out my promise result but I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idType')`. I have a line in my code which is causing the error but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
const idType = useSelector((state) => state.questionnaireData.tmpParams.idType)
```

My function:

```
const getId = async (idType) => {
try {
  const res = await axios.get(`https://www.exampleurl.com/${idType}`)
  return res.data[0]["idtype"];
} catch (err) {
  console.error("idType", err.toJSON());
}
```

My initial state and reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  tmpParams: {
    idType: ""
  }
}

setTmpParams: async (state, action) => {
  const { idtype } = action.payload;
  const tmpParams = {};

  tmpParams.idType = await getId(idtype);
  console.log(tmpParams.idType) // prints a promise object

  return {
    ...state,
    tmpParams: {
      ...state.tmpParams,
      ...tmpParams,
    },
  };
}
```

My promise object:

```
Promise {<pending>}
  [[Prototype]]: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: "Visual"
```

Comment: In the function `getId`, you defined `result` and never used it... Typo? Similarly, `res` is used and never defined.

Comment: That's just a typo. I fixed it

Answer (score -1):

getId is an asynchronous function, so it will return a promise. Therefore the reducer doesn't wait for getId to resolve before continuing execution. A potential solution would be to make your reducer an async function and await getId.

Comment: Hey I edited my question to show what's happening. I made it into an async function and did await getId but now I get an error.

Answer (score -1):

Part of your problem seems to be that you're calling an `async` method from a reducer and this is an **anti-pattern**, since reducers by themselves should not have side effects. Since you're printing the result of your `getById` function, the result is effectively a promise. You would have to `await` on that to get the result you want.

I suggest you refactor your application in a way that allows you to handle side effects more effectively. You could use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or handle side effects in your component (events or `useEffect`) and pass the results into your reducer instead.

Comment: I edited my question as I was able to do it using an async reducer but now I am getting an error

Answer (score -2):

```
setTmpParams: async (state, action) => {
  tmpParams.idType = await getId(idtype);
  console.log(tmpParams.idType) // prints a promise object

  return {
    ...state,
    tmpParams: {
      ...state.tmpParams,
      ...tmpParams,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That prints out the promise result. But I get an error now..I edited my question to show this

Comment: Where do you get `idtype` from?

Comment: From my payload. I updated it in my question

Comment: `return res.data[0]["idtype"];` You probably wanted to use `idtype` instead of `"idtype"`, but I don't know how this data looks like

Comment: Maybe you should `console.log` the result of your axios call to ensure the shape of your data is as expected. If the shape of the data is ok, it should work. Still, I wouldn't recommend calling async methods in reducers.

Comment: that gives `idtype is not defined` error because my data looks like this: `["idtype":"Visual"}]`

Comment: The result of the axios call is "Visual" - same as when I `console.log(tmpParams.idType)`. The error is coming from `tmpParams.testType = await getId(idtype)`

Comment: Wait I just saw that the error comes from another place where I am doing `const idType = useSelector((state) => state.questionnaireData.tmpParams.idType)`